# Serializing struct to file, and deserializing it again with string

Tags: c++, string, serialization, struct, deserialization

I have a following struct :

```
struct ArchiveTableEntry
        {
            uint32_t id;
            char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN + 1];
            uint32_t filename_crc32;
            uint32_t real_data_size;
            uint32_t block_data_size;

            uint32_t data_crc32;
            char data_md5_checksum[16];

            uint64_t data_offset;
            uint8_t flag;
        };
```

And after serialization of it I have good output to file.
Also loading from file work propertly too.
I use **memcpy** to perform serialization/deserialization, and now my question is : **How can I replace char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LEN + 1]; by std::string, and keep serialization/deserialization working with save unused bytes that char waste.**
Thanks!

Comment: `struct` fields might be underlie memory aligned padding ... Use an appropriate serialization mechanism to get size efficient outputs (e.g. google protobuf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid using memcpy-ing to a pointer for serialization.. Instead, make use of streams.. You can even make a stream class that serializes any type of data. Next you'll just have to add << and >> operators to any class that needs to be serialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

struct ArchiveTableEntry
{
    uint32_t id;
    std::string filename;
    uint32_t filename_crc32;
    uint32_t real_data_size;
    uint32_t block_data_size;

    uint32_t data_crc32;
    char data_md5_checksum[16];

    uint64_t data_offset;
    uint8_t flag;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const ArchiveTableEntry entry)
{
    return os << entry.id << entry.filename.size() << entry.filename
              << entry.filename_crc32 << entry.real_data_size << entry.block_data_size
              << entry.data_crc32 << entry.data_md5_checksum << entry.data_offset << entry.flag;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& os, ArchiveTableEntry& entry)
{
    std::size_t filesize = 0;
    os >> entry.id;
    os >> filesize;
    entry.filename.resize(filesize);
    os.read(&entry.filename[0], filesize);
    os >> entry.filename_crc32 >> entry.real_data_size >> entry.block_data_size >> entry.data_crc32;
    os >> entry.data_md5_checksum >> entry.data_offset >> entry.flag;
    return os;
}



int main()
{
    const char* md5_checksum = "some checksum";

    ArchiveTableEntry data;
    data.id = 1;
    data.filename = "file.txt";
    data.filename_crc32 = 10434235;
    data.real_data_size = 1024;
    data.block_data_size = 256;
    data.data_crc32 = 324225252;
    data.data_md5_checksum = 1;

    std::memset(data.data_md5_checksum, 0, sizeof(data.data_md5_checksum) / sizeof(char));
    strcpy(data.data_md5_checksum, md5_checksum);

    data.data_offset = 512;
    data.flag = 1;

    std::fstream out("C:/Users/School/Desktop/Test.bin", std::ios::out);
    if (out.is_open())
    {
        out << data;
        out.close();
    }

    std::fstream in("C:/Users/School/Desktop/Test.bin", std::ios::in);
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        in >> data;
        in.close();
    }

    std::cout<<data.id<<" "<<data.filename<<" "<<data.filename_crc32<<" "<<data.real_data_size<<" "<<data.block_data_size<<" ";
    std::cout<<data.data_crc32<<" "<<data.data_md5_checksum<<" ";
}
```

Comment: "Try to avoid using memcpy-ing to a pointer for serialization." Yes, if you hate performance.

Comment: Lol.. OP was creating a buffer, copying everything to the buffer and writing that to the file. Secondly, he cannot memcpy an `std::string`, which was his issue in the first place. He wasn't writing the length of the string to the file and then the contents. With streams, he doesn't have to copy to a temporary buffer and then write to the file. It also makes his life easier when using other standard library classes.

Comment: You're right about the std::string part. But usually you do serialization/deserialization using a structure you can read/write in one go. This is usually faster than multiple small read/write operations.